# Group by one property while retrieving more with core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a table in Core Data with the following properties:

```
date, name, phone
```

I want to retrieve a list of 5 unique phone numbers with names ordered by date. So in MySQL it would be something like:

```
SELECT name, phone FROM myTable GROUP BY phone ORDER BY date
```

So if I have this list of data:

```
01/23/2015 someName1 12345678
01/21/2015 someName2 12345678
01/21/2015 someOtherName1 987654321
```

I would like to retrieve a list of unique phone numbers with the date field controlling which name to be associated with any duplicated numbers. In this case, the desired result would be:

```
01/23/2015 someName1 12345678
01/21/2015 someOtherName1 987654321
```

However doing this with a `NSFetchRequest` seems a bit complicated since the `setPropertiesToGroupBy` requires to contain the same list of properties as defined in `setPropertiesToFetch`.

In other words, this is how I would think I would be able to do it:

```
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"someEntity" inManagedObjectContext:someContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"name", @"phone"]];
    [request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"phone"]];
    [request setFetchLimit:5];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortByCreatedDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortByCreatedDate]];
```

However I will get an exception on the `propertiesToGroupBy` unless I include the `name` field as well.

How can I achieve what I want without having to manually go through the list?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include a sample of your data, and your desired output?  From your description, I'm not sure you need to use 'group by'.

Comment: @pbasdf of course - see my updated question. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: have you tried?  NSArray *groups = [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.phone"];

Comment: @Jim this will only give me the phone properties, no? I need the names as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a proviso that I **think** this will work; I leave it to you to test it to death:

You cannot add any other attributes to `propertiesToFetch`, beyond those in the `propertiesToGroupBy`, but it seems you can include the `objectID` in the properties to fetch.  To do so, build an `NSExpression` and associated `NSExpressionDescription` for the "evaluated object":

```
NSExpression *selfExp = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
NSExpressionDescription *selfED = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
selfED.name = @"objID";
selfED.expression = selfExp;
selfED.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;
```

Now define another expression/description to get the max(date):

```
NSExpression *maxDate = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"date"];
NSExpression *indexExp = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:@[maxDate]];
NSExpressionDescription *maxED = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
maxED.name = @"maxDate";
maxED.expression = indexExp;
maxED.expressionResultType = NSDateAttributeType;
```

Then include these two expression descriptions in the list of properties to fetch:

```
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"phone", maxED, selfED]];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"phone"]];
```

When you run the fetch, each item in the resulting array will have a key "objID" containing the objectID for the relevant object.  You can unpack that, to access the name, phone, etc, with something along these lines:

```
NSArray *results = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
for (NSDictionary *dict in results) {
    NSDate *maxDate = dict[@"maxDate"];
    NSString *phone = dict[@"phone"];
    NSManagedObjectID *objID = [dict valueForKey:@"objID"];
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.context objectWithID:objID];
    NSString *name = [object valueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

One particular aspect I am unsure of is how this will behave if two rows have exactly the same `date`.

Comment: I assume it should say maxED.expression = maxDate;? However using this approach I am getting this exception: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions (date is not in the GROUP BY)'

Comment: So sorry, I missed a key line whilst cutting/pasting.  I will update the answer....

Comment: @SteffenD.Sommer I have added the line: NSExpression *indexExp = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:@[maxDate]]; in the answer above.